# Why does StatSVN fail, claiming the directory is not a working copy?

Tags: svn, statsvn

I have a working copy of my project, checked out using Subversion 1.5.1. When I attempt to run [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) against it, I get the following error:

> Sep 18, 2008 12:25:22 PM net.sf.statsvn.util.JavaUtilTaskLogger info
>   INFO: StatSVN - SVN statistics generation
>
> Sep 18, 2008 12:25:22 PM net.sf.statsvn.util.JavaUtilTaskLogger info
>   INFO: svn: '.' is not a working copy
>   Sep 18, 2008 12:25:22 PM net.sf.statsvn.util.JavaUtilTaskLogger error
>   SEVERE: Repository root not available - verify that the project was checked out with svn version 1.3.0 or above.

Has anyone experienced this? I've seen suggestions it might be related to using a locale other than `en_US`, but I *am* using `en_US`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing here, but are you sure that statSVN is compatible with working copies created with version 1.5 of the client? The format changed with svn 1.5...

Comment: I can't find any documentation on that one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

@agnul

You were right. Here's the [relevant feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2016015&group_id=164845&atid=833327) from their bugzilla.